# Convert PDF file to images using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, pdf

Using C#, I need to convert each page of a PDF file into separate images and display the images.

Is it possible to do this without using a 3rd party DLL?

Comment: I would take a look at what people responded with to this person who posted just after you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492732/pdf-2-post-script  I think it is a huge job but there are open source libraries that are out there they may be able to help you like itextsharp is ghostscript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use a c# code that is easly downloadable from Code Project
that use Ghostscript

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GhostScriptUseWithCSharp.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Not a huge job, as it has already been done :)

you'll need ghostscript installed (mainly gsdll32.dll), and the c# wrapper from http://redmanscave.blogspot.com/

It's one .cs file. For some reason you'll have to email him for the file, it is not posted.

To convert you'll just a few lines, for example:

```
    string cl2 = @"-dSAFER -dNoVerifyXref -dQUIET -dNOPROMPT"
      + " -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r72 -dFirstPage=1 "
      +  "-dLastPage=1 -dUseCropBox -sOutputFile=" + SourceFile 
      + " " + TargetFile;

    try
    {
        Made4Print.GhostScript gs = 
            new Made4Print.GhostScript(@"[path-to-gs-installation]");
        gs.CallGSDll(cl2.Split(' '));
    }
    catch
    {
        //exception handler
    }
```

this saves 1st page as jpeg @ 72 dpi

Answer (score 1):

I used PDF4NET from O2 a few times in the past and was pretty satisfied
http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm

Comment: Can you provide Example Code?

Answer (score 0):

I have done with this ghost script to convert PDF to Image.hope this one is helpful

"-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=tifflzw -dTextAlphaBits=1 -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile="C:\Users\cis\Desktop\asp634667352520620000.tif" "C:\Users\cis\Desktop\asp.pdf""

Comment: This One Convert Your whole PDF to Image(Tiff) Format