# Replace text in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, image-processing, itext, pdfsharp

I'm trying to replace a section of a PDF with different text. From research on all major PDF libraries for .NET, it seems this is complicated and not a trivial task. I think it may be easier to convert the PDF to an image, replace the text (always in the same place), then convert it back to a PDF (or leave it as an image if converting back isn't possible). Is it possible to extract an image from a PDF page with .NET?

Comment: For exporting PDF files into images, take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492129/converting-pdf-file-to-images-using-c). However, for your original problem, if you can afford a commercial solution I would recommend Amyuni PDF Creator. If the position of the text inside the page is known, it will allow you to select all text inside a specified rectangle, and you can add a new text as replacement. By the way, you can also export the PDF files into images with this product if needed.
Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies.

Answer (score 1):

If your text is in a known location, you can simply cover it with a rectangle filled with the background color, and then draw your text over top.

Note that the text will still be there, it simply won't be visible.  Someone selecting text will still pick up the old stuff.  If that's acceptable, it's quite trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF was created from image, you can import it into Photoshop to edit it as an graphic. Or you can use screenshot program like "Snagit" to capture pdf page as image and use snagit's editor to erase old text and replace new one.

But this method may bring you problem is that the new added text may not the same font as text around it. Personally, I use pdf editor to [replace text in pdf](http://www.convertpdf.org/replace-text-in-pdf.html) since the added text will be automatically fit with the original font and size.